# Normalization to Third Normal Form (3NF)

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have been given the example data and have been struggling to normalize to 3NF. I think the issue lies with the Tutor Name but this is my final chance at submitting so would like to get it right.

[image: Example Data]

This is how I have normalised it,

3NF

**Course**

*Course Code*, Course Title, Level, Mode of Attendance, Course Fee, Start Date, End Date, Department*

**Student/Course**

*Course Code*, *Student ID*, Enrolment Date, Enrolled By

**Student**

*Student ID*, Student First Name, Student Last Name, Student Street, Student Town, Student Postcode, Student Landline, Student Mobile, Student DOB

**Department**

Department, Department Head Title, Department Head First Name, Department Name Last Name, Tutor First Name, Tutor Last Name

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the tutor meant to be a guy that helps each student? I mean, is it a tutor per student, a tutor per every X amount of students or a tutor per Course? (just asking out of sheer ignorance [where I come from there's no tutors, you're on your own, good luck. That's why])

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you could add an additional Entity in there, one that represents people as a part of this (school-like?) institution, call it **"People"** (yeah...)

So `Tutors`, `Students`, `Teachers`, `Head of Departments`, etc are all **People**.
That table will hold Attributes that the sub classes/entities will share (because they're all people, right?): *Firstname*, *Lastname*, *DoB*, etc.

You then refer to this table on your other entities. Eg the `Teachers` by using the FK `PeopleId` (or whatever you call it =)

A student is then able to become a tutor and even a Teacher or a Head of Department at some point without being added to simultaneous tables within the database.

To, then, define a relationship between your `Course`, your `Students` and your `Tutors` you'll use a junction table in between that could look like:

```
------------------
|  CourseTutors  |
------------------
| FK | CourseId  |
| FK | StudentId |
| FK | TutorId   |
------------------
```

Thats very granular, it will even allow you to have one tutor per student.